# eval lock doesn't work

Tags: python, locking, eval

I'm trying to have lock's for similar input strings. But the lock's doesn't work. The second lock for the same string doesn't wait but the first release will destroy the lock so the second release will raise an error.

**test.py**

```
import threading
import time

class TestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.input = input

        lock_wrap = "TestThread." + self.input + " = threading.Lock()"
        eval(compile(lock_wrap,'<string>','exec'))

    def run(self):
        acquire_wrap = "TestThread." + self.input + ".acquire()"
        exec(compile(acquire_wrap,'<string>','exec'))
        print("waste some time for %s" % self.input)
        time.sleep(30)
        print("%s done" % self.input)
        release_wrap = "TestThread." + self.input + ".release()"
        exec(compile(release_wrap,'<string>','exec'))

my_threads = [] 

while True:
    input = raw_input("> ") 
    if input == "end": 
        break 
    thread = TestThread(input)
    my_threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for t in my_threads:
    t.join()
```

**result**

```
$ python test.py 
> foo
> waste some time for foo
bar
waste some time for bar
 > foo
> waste some time for foo
foo done
bar done
foo done
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test.py", line 19, in run
    exec(compile(release_wrap,'<string>','exec'))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
error: release unlocked lock
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using eval for this application doesn't make sense; why not just keep one lock per thread?

```
class TestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.input = input
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        print("waste some time for %s" % self.input)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("%s done" % self.input)
        self.lock.release()
```

You mention wanting to have the same lock for identical strings, but in that case, *of course* when a lock for one string ends, so will the locks for other threads using the same string. Perhaps if you explained your motivation more I could suggest another solution.

ETA: If you're sure that, for your particular application, you want to have the same lock for the same string, this would be one way to do it:

```
LOCK_DICT = {}
LOCK_DICT_LOCK = threading.RLock()

class TestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.input = input

        with LOCK_DICT_LOCK:
            if self.input not in LOCK_DICT:
                LOCK_DICT[self.input] = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        with LOCK_DICT_LOCK:
            lock = LOCK_DICT[self.input]

        lock.acquire()
        print("waste some time for %s" % self.input)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("%s done" % self.input)        
        lock.release()
```

Note that this particular version uses global variables, which isn't ideal design, but it is *much* better than using `eval` as in your design above (which also kept the variables as class properties). Whatever code you use can of course put LOCK_DICT and LOCK_DICT_LOCK somewhere that isn't global (say, a class you call ThreadManager).

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Now I just have to learn how it works, haha. Many Thanks David!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Again, make sure that you do want to use the same lock for multiple threads before you use this.